# Handle emails in a Rails 7 Multitenant Web App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, multi-tenant

I'm developing a multi tenant (with apartment gem) dashboard application with Rails 7. I've bought my own domain for the application but I have no email service yet.

**How does my app work?**

1. A customer sign up for it
2. He can decide to use a custom subdomain like customer1.example.com to reach his dashboard
3. He also can chose to use his own domain like customer1.com. I've handled this part with cloudflare for SaaS feature
4. He will use his own dashboard to let other people join, create accounts, interact with that dashboard

**What am I looking for?**

I'm looking for the best solution to implement these features:

- Sending and receiving email for my application: something like info@mydomain.com, support@mydomain.com etc... (and this is the "easy" part. I think I simply need an email host

Here's come the (for my little experience) hard part:

1. How can I create a system of mail for actions like signup confirmation etc? I think those could just be some sort of "from" email and don't really need to exists.
2. How can I let the customer send/receive mail sent for example to customer1@mydomain.com or info-customer1@mydomain.com?

In case I just said something really stupid, what should be the correct way to handle emailing in an application like this?

Thanks to everyone, tell me if you need more information!

Answer (score 0):

- `customer1@mydomain.com` and `info-customer1@mydomain.com` are mailboxes.
- You should create the setting for each company and use it to send/receive the email. For dynamically, you can create options to select belike `"send as a mailbox"`
- If you want to find a product to manage sent/received emails from many mailboxes, you can try [this](https://chartdesk.pro/) instead of implementing